# How do I fit my function with data to get fit parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a set of data where x and y are the known parameters in my function, they are written in the function as x=x and y=x1, and I need to fit the data so I can get values for the unknown parameters (E, B0, S0).
I have this so far but when I try to run this I get the error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4L,) and (1L,)
```

This error happens when I try to plot the against the fit curve. Also I get this error in regards to the bounds I have setup:

```
 lb, ub = [np.asarray(b, dtype=float) for b in bounds]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func (x, x1, E, B0, S0):
    # function to optimize where x and x1 are known
    # E, B0, S0 need to be fitted
    return sum((x-np.power((E*B0*(1+((x1-S0)/(B0)))),(1/2)))**2)

#define the data to be fit
xdata = [0.00, 3.42, 4.56, 5.31] #distance
ydata = [335.4, 149.1, 167.1, 292.2] # beam size
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
pl.show()

# fit for parameters E, B0, and S0
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')

#put bounds on the optimization: 0.5<E<5, 1<S0<10, 0.1<B0,10
bnds= [(0.5,5.0),(0.1,10.0),(1,10)]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds = [(0.5,5.0),(0.1,10.0),
(1.0,10.0)])
plt.plot(xdata,func(xdata, *popt),'g--', label='fit-with-bounds')
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.ylabel('beam size')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the sum in the `func` function is supposed to do. You may leave it out to get rid of the first error.

Second, the bounds in the curve_fit method are the bounds for the *independent*  variable, not for the parameters. Leave the bounds out and you'll get rid of the second error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func (x, x1, E, B0, S0):
    # function to optimize where x and x1 are known
    # E, B0, S0 need to be fitted
    return (x-np.power((E*B0*(1.+((x1-S0)/(B0)))),(1/2.)))**2

#define the data to be fit
xdata = [0.00, 3.42, 4.56, 5.31] #distance
ydata = [335.4, 149.1, 167.1, 292.2] # beam size
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')


# fit for parameters E, B0, and S0
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata) 
plt.plot(xdata,func(xdata, *popt),'g--', label='fit-with-bounds')
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.ylabel('beam size')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now obviously "fit" and "fit-with-bounds" are the same.

---

Edit: To fit for `E, B0, S0` only, the fit function should only take those values as arguments.

```
funcwithx1 = lambda x,x1, E, B0, S0: (x-np.power((E*B0*(1.+((x1-S0)/(B0)))),(1/2.)))**2
x1 = 4.6
func = lambda x, E, B0, S0: funcwithx1(x, x1, E, B0, S0)
```

Comment: Okay this was helpful. If I print popt, which gives the fitted parameters, I get 4 values but I am only fitting for three parameters, E, B0, and S0. Also is there a way to bound the parameters? And I see that you added a period after the 1. and (1/2.) in my function and that makes a great difference in the way the plot turns out, why did you do that? Thanks once again.

Comment: In python 2 `1/2 == 0`, but `1/2.0 == 0.5`. Your function is fitting four parameters `(x1, E, B0, S0)`.

Comment: I don't want to fit for x1, that is a known value and it's the xdata array. How do I fix my function to just fit for E,B0,and S0?

Comment: The fit function should only take those parameters that are to be optimized for. I updated the answer.

Comment: I rewrote the function in the correct form where y= func(x:params) so now it is:                                                                                                 def func (x, E, B0, S0):
    # function to optimize where x known
    # E, B0, S0 need to be fitted
    return (1. + np.power((E*B0*(1.+((x-S0)/(B0)))),(1/2.)))                                     But when I go to plot this I get the error the RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800. I tried re scaling my data and putting in better initial guesses for my params

Answer (score 0):

The function is wrongly defined. You know the independent and dependent variables, but you only supply the independent one to the fitted function.

`y = func(x; params)`

as it stands now, your objective function has 4 parameters to be determined.

Later on, when invoking the curve_fit you supply both, the independent and dependent variables as you correctly do in 
`popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)`

Thus, `popt` is an array of length 4 and probably causing you part of your problems.

I don't know exactly your objective function, so I'll not attempt to fix that. Hope this guides you to solve the issue.

Comment: x and x1 are the known parameters, x is the xdata array and x1 is the ydata array and I am trying to fit for E, B0, and S0. So in my function how do I supply the both the dependent and independent variable?

Comment: As I said, you don't supply x and y to your function but to the fitting procedure in `curve_fit` (that part is correctly done in your code).

Comment: Sorry x is the ydata array and x1 is the xdata array.

Comment: That doesn't change the situation. BTW, why not to call them x and y and avoid such naming issues?

Comment: I rewrote the function in the correct form where y= func(x:params) so now it is:  def func (x, E, B0, S0): # function to optimize where x known # E, B0, S0 need to be fitted return (1. + np.power((E*B0*(1.+((x-S0)/(B0)))),(1/2.)))    But when I go to plot this I get the error the RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800. I tried re scaling my data and putting in better initial guesses for my parameters, but I still get the error.