# How to do Non-Linar Curve fitting using Python with user defined function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following dataset:

```
x = 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 20, 30

y = 18035.21768722, 18176.09871938, 18370.22289623, 18430.68522672, 18490.76110193, 18512.69861061
```

Now, I want to plot this data and fit this data set with my defined function `f(x) = (A*K*x/1+K*x)` and find the parameters `A` and `K` ?

I wrote the following python script but it seems like it can't do the fitting I require:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.array([2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 20, 30])

y = np.array([18035.21768722, 18176.09871938, 18370.22289623, 18430.68522672, 18490.76110193, 18512.69861061])

def func(x, A, K):

    return (A*K*x / 1+K*x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'b-', label='data')


popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')

plt.xlabel('x')

plt.ylabel('y')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Can anyone help me with the changes in the python script or a new script where I can properly fit the data with my desired fitting function ?

Comment: Did you mean `(A*K*x / (1+K*x))` instead of `(A*K*x / 1+K*x)`?

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fit my function with data to get fit parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632960/how-do-i-fit-my-function-with-data-to-get-fit-parameters)

Comment: These two questions of yours are duplicates: [How to do Non-Linar Curve fitting and find fitting parameter using Python with user defined function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519417/how-to-do-non-linar-curve-fitting-and-find-fitting-parameter-using-python-with-u)

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your function definition as suggested by HS-nebula in the comments, and add an initial guess for `k` using the `p0` argument in `curve_fit`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


x = np.array([2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 20, 30])
y = np.array([18035.21768722, 18176.09871938, 18370.22289623, 18430.68522672, 18490.76110193, 18512.69861061])


def func(x, A, K):
    return A*K*x / (1+K*x)


plt.plot(x, y, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=[1, 1e6])

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]